# Make variable equal to UserDefaults for timer

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UIProgress view that takes 60 seconds to go across the screen, but how do I make it where rather than having a set time 'var seconds = 60' I have the UserDefault string be the time? (Not all the code is included.)

```
import UIKit

class MinuteMeditation: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var progressController: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

let savedTime = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "time")

var seconds = 60 // THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE USER DEFAULTS ^
var timer = Timer()
var isTimerRunning = false
var resumeTapped = false


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    runTimer()
```

Comment: `if let savedTime = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "time"), let time = Double(savedTime) { seconds = time }` either in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` depending on when you would prefer it to be loaded

Comment: You could also make `seconds` a computed property, but that would depend on what it is you want to achieve

Comment: I would assume a "default" value

Comment: *"This didn't work for me"* isn't a problem description, nor is it helpful - since I've provided two possible solutions two and out-of-context piece of code it's difficult to "what" hasn't worked nor "how" you've tried to apply it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to assign the value at some point in the `UIViewController`s life-cycle, for example, you could use `viewWillLoad` if you want to use the saved value EVERY time the view is shown, or `viewLoaded` if you only want to set when the view is first loaded by the system, for example...

```
class MinuteMeditation: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var progressController: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    var seconds: TimeInterval = 60.0 // THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE USER DEFAULTS ^
    var timer = Timer()
    var isTimerRunning = false
    var resumeTapped = false

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let savedTime = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "time"), let time = Double(savedTime) {
            seconds = time
        }
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        runTimer()
    }
}
```

Just remember, this will ALWAYS override any value previous set.  If you prefer to only use the saved value if the value hasn't previously been set, you will need to make `seconds` optional and assign a default value when it hasn't previously been set and there is no saved value

Another option is to make `seconds` a computed value...

```
class MinuteMeditation: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var progressController: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    var seconds: TimeInterval {
        guard let savedTime = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "time"), let time = Double(savedTime) else {
            return 60.0
        }
        return time
    }
    var timer = Timer()
    var isTimerRunning = false
    var resumeTapped = false

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        runTimer()
    }
}
```

This does mean that the value will never be settable directly, it will only be settable via the `UserDefaults`